# How iterate with tweepy, correction

Tags: python, tweepy

I want to extract the Twitter text relevant to a stock market stock and I am using the `tweepy` library, I have seen in blogs that iterate like the published code, but I get errors when iterating.

```
import sys, tweepy, csv, re

consumerKey = 'XXX'
consumerSecret = 'XXX'
accessToken = 'XXX'
accessTokenSecret = 'XXXX'

def DownloadData():
  #Autenticacion 
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
  auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
  api = tweepy.API(auth)

  #Enter Stock y cantidad de busqueda
  searchStock = input('Enter stock name: ')
  numOfSearch = int(input('Enter how many tweets to search  '))

  #searching tweets
  tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchStock, lang = "en",).items(numOfSearch) 

  tweets = DownloadData()
  for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    tweets.next()

Enter stock name: amazon
Enter how many tweets to search 10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d80e20f5a4da> in <module>()
      1 tweets = DownloadData()
----> 2 for tweet in tweets:
      3   print(tweet.text)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: because you are overwriting tweets variable

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable tweets which store all tweets by function `DownloadData`.
Here is correct working solution.

```
def DownloadData():
    #Autenticacion 
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
    auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
      
    #Enter Stock y cantidad de busqueda
    searchStock = input('Enter stock name: ')
    numOfSearch = int(input('Enter how many tweets to search  '))
      
    #searching tweets
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchStock, lang = "en",).items(numOfSearch) 
    for tweet in tweets:
      print(tweet.text)
      
DownloadData()
```

There is no need of `tweets.next()`